# SSRS parameter to select "future" or "past" dates. (contracts expired or current by expiration date)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

What expression and dataset query structure would I use to add a drop-down filter to filter contract records by date, selecting either "Expired", ExpirationDate < Today(), Or "Current", ExpirationDate >= Today()?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a parameter along with a dataset filter.

1. Add a new parameter to the report.
2. Set the Available Values to "Expired" and "Current".
3. Add a Filter to your DataSet with the expression to check each row. For example:

   =IIf(Parameters!MyParam.Value = "Expired" And Fields!ExpirationDate.Value < Today, true, IIf(Parameters!MyParam.Value = "Current" And Fields!ExpirationDate.Value >= Today, true, false))

The Filter should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so, add a parameter with "Expired" and "Current" as the available values and a filter with the expression.  What would I put in the DataSet1 query.  Sorry if I'm being dense.  Also, how would I make the default to show all of the records?  Thanks.

Comment: I added a parameter with "Expired" and "Current" as the Available Values. Allow blank value and Allow null value checked.  No default value set.   In the dataset I added the expression above into a Filter, in the Expression field with no other settings made in the Filter (no Operator or Value.  Just Expression.)  I got an error stating:  "Cannot compare data types System.Boolean and System.String."

Comment: @DavidMegnin please see the screenshot I added. The DataSet I'm referring to is your existing main query.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't put "true" in the Value field.  I rarely use the filters so I'm not very familiar with how to use them.  Oh, and I just noticed the Boolean setting as well.  I'll fix those and give it another go.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, no error this time, but both selections return no rows of data.  Here is my filter expression:    =IIf(Parameters!ExpirationDate.Value = "Expired" And Fields!ContractExpirationDate.Value < Today, true, IIF(Parameters!ExpirationDate.Value = "Current" And Fields!ContractExpirationDate.Value >= Today, true, false))           [how do you add a 'new line' in stackoverflow?]    My parameter is "ExpirationDate"  and the SQL field is "ContractExpirationDate.  Do I have the expression right?  Should I replace "Today" with "GetDate()"?

Comment: @DavidMegnin It sounds like you're on the right track. `Today` is the current date. There must be something else going on. To test it, you could remove the filter and then add that expression in a cell in your results to see how it is evaluating for each row.